# POST projects in Toggl through API

Tags: javascript, json, api, curl

I'm developing an **API** to integrate the **Knack** with **Toggl**. So, I need to **post** some data in the Toggl using an API that will be running in **Google Script (JavaScript**).

When I try to post somes projects in the Toggl, I receive the following error: *"Request failed for https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects returned code 400. Truncated server response: Project can't be blank (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 61, file "")"*

My source code is:

```
function sendDataToToggl(){
   var apiToken = '936e292eaccd99b40358edea25452880';  
   var unamepass = apiToken + ":api_token"; 
   var digest = Utilities.base64Encode(unamepass);
   var digestfull = "Basic " + digest;
   var url = "https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects";
   var data = {"project":{"name":"An awesome project","wid":1034130,"template_id":1793088,"is_private":true,"cid":123397}};
   var options = { 
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "method": "post",
                   "headers": {"Authorization": digestfull},
                   "payload": data
                   //"muteHttpExceptions": true 
                 };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change options:

- `Content-Type` to `contentType` - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
- `"payload": data` to `"payload": JSON.stringify(data)` - will generate JSON string as payload.

Also, as you publicly posted your API key, you might want to get a new one.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the following error after the modifications: "Request failed for https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/projects returned code 400. Truncated server response: Name has already been taken (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)". About the API key, this one is just for test :)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Now my code worked ! I had to comment the field "wid" in addition to the changes you suggested.